# Enforce rules in a stock transaction table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

I'm creating a fake stock market type database and the `Transaction` table needs some sort of logic to enforce certain rules. Here's the `Transaction` table I'm using:

```
Id  AccountId   Action  Qty Price   Amount
1   1           SELL    30  $1.00   $30.00
2   2           BUY     30  $1.00   -$30.00
3   1           SELL    20  $2.00   $40.00
4   3           BUY     20  $2.00   -$40.00
5   3           DEPOSIT            $100.00
```

As you can see here `BUY/SELL` Actions must have a `Qty` and `Price` and an `Amount` that should be calculated. The DEPOSIT action doesn't require `Qty` or `Price` because thats just a user putting money into an `Account` table

I was thinking of using some sort of trigger to do this. Is there a better practice?

Comment: Imo a [check constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258(v=sql.105).aspx) would be preferable.

Comment: Since buys, sells and deposits have different requirements, one could argue that you should use separate tables tailored to the requirements of each.  That would [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the design and allow simple constraints on the columns.  A trigger would be appropriate if you wanted to prevent shorting stocks, i.e. selling a block of stock that you don't hold.

Comment: @HABO - Is there a particular pattern for this type of thing? I feel as though a single table for all transactions makes most sense since I have other tables referencing it. I also have a trigger setup for the Account table that updates the balance

Comment: triggers are bad practice. if you can make deposit(depositid, amount) as different table and QTY adn PRICE as NOT NULL FIELDS that will make easier.

Comment: Mixing different data in a single table is a judgement call.  Something like `Addresses` where some entries have two lines of street address, some have an apartment number, ..., are pretty easy to handle by allowing NULLs appropriately.  When you start getting into buy/sell transactions having a price, quantity, commission, fees, lot number(s), transaction and settlement dates, ... vs a deposit or withdrawal, it looks like they are different enough to warrant separate tables.  A few `JOIN`s and `UNION`s are easier to handle than a bunch of rules based on the contents of a column.

Comment: @HABO - I see your point and agree. What I think I may do is just have a simple transaction table `Id, AccountId, Description, Amount`. that table just controls the flow of funds. I'll have a separate `OrderActivity` table that has the `Qty` and `Price` along with a `TransactionId` to tie the two together

Comment: Do SELL and BUY always come as a pair and do `Qty` and `Price` always match in that pair? Your example seems to suggest that.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - No there's a SELLALL and SELL which can be any number of shares as long as its less then what the seller is selling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in SQL Server 2012. (Stock symbols are omitted.)

```
create table stock_transactions (
  trans_id integer primary key,
  trans_ts datetime not null default current_timestamp,
  account_id integer not null, -- references accounts, not shown

  -- char(1) keeps the table narrow, while avoiding a needless
  -- join on an integer. 
  -- (b)uy, (s)ell, (d)eposit
  action char(1) not null check (action in ('b', 's', 'd')),

  qty integer not null check (qty > 0),

  -- If your platform offers a special data type for money, you
  -- should probably use it. 
  price money not null check (price > cast(0.00 as money)),

  -- Assumes it's not practical to calculate amounts on the fly
  -- for many millions of rows. If you store it, use a constraint
  -- to make sure it's right. But you're better off starting
  -- with a view that does the calculation. If that doesn't perform
  -- well, try an indexed view, or (as I did below) add the 
  -- "trans_amount" column and check constraint, and fix up
  -- the view. (Which might mean just including the new "trans_amount"
  -- column, or might mean dropping the view altogether.)
  trans_amount money not null,

  -- Only (b)uys always result in a negative amount.
  check ( 
    trans_amount = (case when action = 'b' then qty * price * (-1)
                         else                   qty * price
                    end )
  ),

  -- (d)eposits always have a quantity of 1. Simple, makes logical 
  -- sense, avoids NULL and avoids additional tables.
  check ( 
    qty = (case when action = 'd' then 1 end)
  )
);

insert into stock_transactions values
(1, current_timestamp, 1, 's', 30,   1.00,   30.00),
(2, current_timestamp, 2, 'b', 30,   1.00,  -30.00),
(3, current_timestamp, 1, 's', 20,   2.00,   40.00),
(4, current_timestamp, 3, 'b', 20,   2.00,  -40.00),
(5, current_timestamp, 3, 'd',  1, 100.00,  100.00);
```

But look at what happened. Now that we've added deposits as a type of transaction, this is no longer a table of stock transactions. Now it's more like a table of account transactions.

You'll need more than a CHECK constraint to make sure that an account has enough in it to buy whatever the account holder wants to buy.

In SQL Server, decisions about clustered indexes are important. Give that some thought and testing. I'd expect you to query often on account id numbers.